# Push next view Pagemenu ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I am using Page menu in application and i want to push from didSelectRowAtIndexPath in next view in one view which is involed in page menu [image]

i know all way which we use for push and model.if i am using model with custom navigation bar then page menu hide on dismiss model.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumed hierarchy:**

UINavigation Controller -- UIViewController -- UIPageController

UIPageController (with 2 UIViewController) -- UITableViewController-1   and   UITableViewController-2

**On didSelectRowAtIndexPath method**

UIPageController -- UITableViewController-1  //Selected any one row

Then just push the next view controller onto the current UITableViewController.

Note - Both controller in UIPageController maintain separate life cycle that is independent from each other.

Comment: I am just give the  Identifier    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"chat" sender:nil];
and i do the source controller embed in navigation controller and from page menu i present  my both thats why push method not working  even i tried one view embed in navigation but not worked

Comment: both view controller*

Comment: Try to push the newViewController on tableViewController (which is added as subview in pageController.. right ?).

Comment: Check this [PageController tut](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) for info and verify if you missing out anything on pageController.

Comment: yes but getting error source controller need navigation but there is already source controller is navigation controller

Comment: Please share the code and error that come on console.

Comment: Error:-Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'chat'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
i set the identifier  like we all do simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98299/discussion-between-nikhil84-and-rushang-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

One can not push the viewcontroller in pageView , PageviewController don't have navigation controller .

**Solution :**

There are two ways to make this possible suggested by [Nitin Gohel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280373/nitin-gohel)

1. set notification for event and Retrieve the notification on main Controller

You can send the information in Notification required in another viewController.

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"abc": @"aaa"};

NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"One" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

In MainViewController just set the onserver for that notification in viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(OneNoti:) name:@"One" object:nil];
}
```

And perform push from MainViewController:

```
-(void) OneNoti:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSNumber* total = (NSNumber*)userInfo[@"total"];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received test notification! %i", total.intValue);
NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1_" sender:nil];
}
```

2. Set the delegate methods in MainView Controller and call the methods while performing action from page view and push from that Action .

Same like above way .

Comment: Got it men :) Thanks a lot and awsm and simple way  @Devang

Comment: @nikhil84  i know your way is best but no working for me hope its working for other guys :)